# Ignore events if another event fires with Rx

Tags: c#, .net, linq, event-handling, system.reactive

#### In short

Looking for a way to achieve

> observableOne.SkipIf(observableTwoFiresWithinPeriod)

#### Explanation

- Let's say I am observing people walking through a door (`walkins Observable`)
- and I also have a way to tell if they have a phone (`phoneWalkins Observable`).
- Now I would like to observe the other piece of the pie of people walking through the door without a phone (`nonPhoneWalkins Observable`)

Given I have `walkins` and the `phoneWalkins` subset available to me as streams then `nonPhoneWalkins` should be `walkins` except `phoneWalkins`.

- How to implement that with Reactive Extensions?
- Note that `phoneWalkins` signals just after `walkins` if the person is found to carry a phone

Comment: You can apply the solution from @LeeCampbell to this problem. Just omit the `Where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my simple try:

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // all walkins
            var walkins =
                // all persons through a door each second
                Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Scheduler.CurrentThread)
                // if has phone (is even) then true, if not false
                .Select(i => (i % 2 == 0));

            var phoneWalkins = // substream of phoneWalkins (if you want it separate)
                walkins
                .Where(i => (i == true))
                .Select(i => i);

            var nonPhoneWalkins = // substream of nonPhoneWalkins (if want it separate)
                walkins
                .Where(i => (i == false))
                .Select(i => i);

            //walkins.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine); // output all
            phoneWalkins.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine); // output phone
            //nonPhoneWalkins.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine); // output nonPhone
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the situation I have meaning phoneWalkins and nonPhoneWalkins are not directly derivable from walkins i.e. phoneWalkins is an independent measurement source e.g. Bob is hired to count people walking in with phones but a CCTV camera counts walk-ins indiscriminately

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @supertopi for pointing to another relevant question, and the answer of @LeeCampbell there ported to this context should work:

```
nonPhoneWalkins = 
    walkins.SelectMany
    (walkin => 
        phoneWalkins.Take(1).Select(phoneWalkin => false)
        .Amb(
            Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(l => true)
            )
    )
    .Where(nonPhoneWalkin => nonPhoneWalkin);
```